# remove part of some values in column from table1 that is found in table2 status is inactive

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

Hi I am new to mysql I have two tables I wanted to remove  part of some values in column table1 that is found in table2 which is status is inactive

My query is like this for table1

```
Select list_name from table1;

Result

list_name
anna;carol;jess;lina;elsa
```

but I want to remove carol and elsa because in table2 they are inactive

```
table 2 query
select name,status from table2


name          status
anna          active
carol         inaactive
jess          active
lina          active
elsa          inactive
```

my expected output  is

```
 name
 anna;jess;lina;
```

Comment: why do you have multiple names in single row in table1?

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values in a delimited list in a string!

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query

```
select replace(GROUP_CONCAT(t1.list_name ), ',', ';') from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.name=t1.list_name 
where t2.status = 'active'
```

Answer (score 0):

You must to use a `INNER JOIN` statement:

```
SELECT 
   t1.list_name
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t1.list_name = t2.name 
WHERE t2.status <> 'inactive'
```

So that you will filter by status.